# Linking Records in R

Tags: r, dplyr, pattern-matching

I'm working with a large amount of administrative data (~22 million records) and am trying to link individuals over time. I know that each row represents a unique individual for a given year, but (with some exceptions that I can use to test my methods accuracy) I don't have an ID to link people over time.

I'm currently trying to figure out a way to pick matches based on year overlaps. So if I see John Smith in company A in 2010 and 2011, and John Smith in company B in 2012 and 2013, I want to say that they are the same person. I have code to do this, but it fails if there is also a John Smith in Company C in 2010-2013. As an extra complication, if there is a John Smith in Company D in 2012 and 2013, then I don't want to connect John Smith in Company A to either John Smith in B or D.

I think what I want to do is to collapse the data by the name fields and create lists of years then compare whether lists are contiguous across companies. I've been using a group_by approach so far, but am open to other suggestions.

I will only need to run this code once to create the links, so efficiency is not the most important issue. This is a toy example, in my actual case I'm using many more fields and multiple levels of progressively less restrictive matching rules.

Most of the fuzzy matching examples/questions I've seen are based on linking two datasets together, and I could split my data into one dataset per year (~20 years), but that seems like the wrong approach.

```
# Testing data
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)


test <- tribble(
  ~year, ~first, ~last, ~company,
  2010, 'john', 'smith', 'a',
  2011, 'john', 'smith', 'a',  
  2012, 'john', 'smith', 'b', 
  2013, 'john', 'smith', 'b',
  2010, 'john', 'smith', 'c',
  2011, 'john', 'smith', 'c',
  2012, 'john', 'smith', 'c',
  2013, 'john', 'smith', 'c',
  2012, 'john', 'smith', 'd',
  2013, 'john', 'smith', 'd'
) 

test$index <- 1:nrow(test)


# Simple case matching
test1 <- filter(test, company %in% c("a", "b"))

# Match on all fields, keeps John's separate
test1 %>% 
  group_by(first, last, company) %>% 
  mutate(id = if_else(!anyDuplicated(year), min(index), 0L)) %>% 
  ungroup()

# Some fields, partial match, Johns are linked
test1 %>% 
  group_by(first, last) %>% 
  mutate(id = if_else(!anyDuplicated(year), min(index), 0L)) %>% 
  ungroup()

# Confounding Group, partial match gets blocked
test2 <- test %>% filter(company %in% c("a", "b", "c"))

test2 %>% 
  group_by(first, last) %>% 
  mutate(id = if_else(!anyDuplicated(year), min(index), 0L)) %>% 
  ungroup()

# Potential Approach
test2 %>% 
  group_by(first, last, company) %>% 
  summarize(year = list(year))
# check if lists are contiguous, if so link??

# If multiple potential matches, shouldn't link
# full test set includes company d, now cant link john smith from a to c
```

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that given your present data structure of `year`, `name` and `company` you can only link with confidence where a person's name is unique throughout the dataset.

Consider the following:

```r
test <- tribble(
  ~year, ~first, ~last, ~company, interpretation 1, interpretation 2, interpretation 3
  2010, 'john', 'smith', 'a',             1                 1                 1
  2011, 'john', 'smith', 'a',             1                 1                 2
  2010, 'john', 'smith', 'b',             2                 2                 3
  2011, 'john', 'smith', 'b',             2                 2                 4
  2012, 'john', 'smith', 'b',             2                 2                 5
  2013, 'john', 'smith', 'b',             2                 2                 6
  2013, 'john', 'smith', 'c',             2                 3                 7
)
```

As written you can not tell whether this is

- Interpretation 1: 2 Johns, one who worked two jobs in 2013
- Interpretation 2: 3 Johns, each who worked at a different company
- Interpretation 3: 7 Johns, who all worked one year each

#### This would be better

A much stronger format would be to have start and end dates:

```r
start_date, end_date,   name, company
2010-01-01, 2011-12-01, john,  a
2010-01-01, 2013-12-01, john,  b
2013-01-01, 2013-12-01, john,  c
```

This makes it clear that it can not be interpretation 1 or 3 (though there are other options, so it might not be interpretation 2 either).

From here you can do something like the following to identify how many other records each record might link to:

```r
test %>%
  inner_join(test, by = 'name', suffix = c("","_c") %>% # suffix _c for comparison
  filter(end_date < start_date_c | end_date_c < start_date) %>% # periods do not overlap
  group_by(start_date, end_date, name, company) %>%
  summarize(num_possible_links = n_dist(start_date_c))
```

Then any record with `num_possible_links != 1` can not be linked. This is because either `num_possible_links = 0` and there is nothing to link with or `num_possible_links > 1` so there are multiple options and one can not be chosen with certainty.

You can then use very similar code to the above to link together identities where `num_possible_links = 1`.

#### But it is not perfect

But at this point you run into one further snag: How big a gap in employment is acceptable? Suppose your data looked like this:

```r
start_date, end_date,   name, company
2010-01-01, 2010-12-01, john,  a
2011-01-01, 2011-12-01, john,  b
2012-01-01, 2012-12-01, john,  c
```

This could be the same John at three different companies. But it could also be 2 Johns, one who worked at company b for a year, and the other who worked at company a and c with a year overseas/unemployed in the middle.

Without some more variables to link on, or some additional assumptions, moving beyond this point is going to be very difficult.